# What maven plugins can I use to restructure an existing EAR

Tags: java, maven, ant, dependencies

I have an EAR that was previously built using Maven.  As part of a new validation process, this EAR will first be uploaded (for scanning purposes) to a third party SAAS before being put into production.  However, prior to uploading the EAR, the contents/structure have to be modified.  I need to be able to repackage my EAR such that only a subset of the libs remain in the WEB-INF/lib folder; the rest either to be moved anywhere else in the EAR (could be at the root level, in a subfolder, in the /lib subfolder, etc - anywhere but within the war). I realize that the EAR may not be deployable, but that is acceptable.

```
EAR
|-lib
 \- shared1.jar
 \- shared2.jar
|- WebApp1.war
 \- images
 \- WEB-INF
  \- lib
   \- lib1.jar
   \- lib2.jar
   \- lib3.jar
|- WebApp2.war
 \- images
 \- WEB-INF
  \- lib
   \- libA.jar
   \- libB.jar
   \- libC.jar
|- EJB1.jar
|- JarModule1.jar
```

In essence, I need to maintain only a subset of my top-level dependencies in my WEB-INF/lib folder.  Any transitive dependencies are to be removed from WEB-INF/lib.

I can do this using something like ANT, but is there anything that exists in the Maven world which would allow me to do this?  I figure I would need to use the maven-dependency-plugin:unpack, but can't quite figure out the right configuration.

If I only list my EAR as a dependency and unpack it, it won't recursively unpack the WARs.

I suspect my only real option is to use ANT/IVY to do this, but I was looking to see if anyone had other creative ideas that I could use to stay in the Maven world.

Comment: You can do many things via maven-assembly-plugin or you can use maven-ear-plugin during the creation of the EAR and extract things into `lib`  folder during the creation process.

Comment: @khmarbaise - My process needs to start from a pre-existing EAR and unfortunately not during the EAR packaging process.  I have yet to be able to find a way to explode a WAR file that is contained within an EAR.

Comment: Use maven-assembly-plugin....for this.